# PHP - Need help figuring out why RestAPI wont respond with my Curl call

Tags: php, rest, curl

I have a curl call that I will use to get data from a RestAPI but no mather what I do I end up with a 404 error. When I run the query string directly in the browser it works for some reason even tho I am using the same headers and authentication.

Here you can see the Curl call that is being made:

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$headers = [];
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

The query URL is being built up by a `custom build query` function as seen below. This is mostly to avoid an issue I had with the URL not formating correctly:

```php
function custom_build_query($query_data) {

    $query = [];

    foreach ($query_data as $name => $value) {

        $value = (array) $value;

        array_walk_recursive($value, function($value) use (&$query, $name) {

            $query[] = urlencode($name) . '=' . urlencode($value);
            
        });
    }
    return implode("&", $query);
}
```

Here you can see the whole code:

```php
<?php

function custom_build_query($query_data) {

    $query = [];

    foreach ($query_data as $name => $value) {

        $value = (array) $value;

        array_walk_recursive($value, function($value) use (&$query, $name) {

            $query[] = urlencode($name) . '=' . urlencode($value);
            
        });
    }
    return implode("&", $query);
}


$SupplierIdentification = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$username = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

$orgnr          =   $_COOKIE['orgnr'];
$company_name   =   $_COOKIE['company_name'];
$adress         =   $_COOKIE['adress'];
$city           =   $_COOKIE['city'];
$post           =   $_COOKIE['post'];
$fornavn        =   $_COOKIE['fornavn'];
$etternavn      =   $_COOKIE['etternavn'];
$telefon        =   $_COOKIE['telefon'];
$email          =   $_COOKIE['email'];
$creditRating   =   $_COOKIE['creditRating'];
$malepunkt      =   $_COOKIE['malepunkt_id'];

$data_array = [
    'company_info'  => [
        'orgnr'             => $orgnr,
        'company_name'      => $company_name,
        'adress'            => $adress,
        'city'              => $city,
        'post'              => $post,
        'creditRating'      => $creditRating,
    ],
    'contact_info' => [
        'fornavn'           => $fornavn,
        'etternavn'         => $etternavn,
        'telefon'           => $telefon,
        'email'             => $email
    ],
    'MeteringPoints'        => $malepunkt
];

$malere = [];

foreach ($malepunkt as $malepunkt){

    array_push($malere, $malepunkt);
}


$query_url = "https://esmart24web.no/tk/api/ischange/api/elhubmeteringpoints?";

$query = [
    'utilityType'                   =>  'ElectricalPower',
    'supplierIdentification'        =>  $SupplierIdentification,
    'organizationNumber'            =>  $orgnr,
    'meteringPointIdentification'   =>  $malere
];

foreach ($malepunkt as $malepunkt){

    $query += ['meteringPointIdentification'    =>  $malepunkt];
}

$query_url .=  custom_build_query($query,'','&');

echo $query_url;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$headers = [];
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: So what does the actual URL you are successfully calling in your browser look like? _"even tho I am using the same headers and authentication."_ - you made your browser send the request with an `Accept: application/json` header, by simply putting the URL into the address bar ...? I rather doubt that.

Comment: So you are saying that the url generated by `$query_url .=  custom_build_query($query,'','&');` works OK when used directly in the browser yet fails in this curl request?

Comment: **When I run the query string directly in the browser it works** - have you tried to use something like postman? or better, a good old curl from command line. also, do double check the url you generate, not to mention watch for the response they gave you - even when you fail.

Comment: I have tried Postman with the same authentication and it works. The URL in  ```$query_url```works when put in browser.